# How to do beveled curves with changing cross sectional shape along the curve?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, bevel

CG artist Mike Campau creates what looks like beveled curves (below), but the cross sectional shape changes along the curve. Is there a trick to this or does he take the time and effort to manually manipulate a mesh to get these inspiring effects?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use a Curve Modifier on an object. The object could be a deformed cylinder segment with an Array Modifier and a Displacement Modifier on it. I created using this technique the following image:

[image]

There where a couple things that I would like to mention here on this model. Firstly I used an 8 segment cylinder as base mesh and deformed it to make it a little more flat. Before the Displacement Modifier there is a Subdivision Modifier in the Modifier list. For the Displacement Modifier there is also one very important thing to mention: Texture Mapping. You couldn't use UV because it would repeat each segment so I used the Local Coordinates. The reason why this whole texture mapping thing is so imported is because the Clouds Texture I wanted to use has to be stretched along the curve. I achieved that by scaling the object factor 10 on the (in my case X axis) and then in edit mode scale everything factor 0.1 so it looks the same as before but now the textures are stretched. This scaling sadly renders the array modifiers fit curve function unusable. For the Array Modifier which comes first in the Modifier list enable the Merge function. There is also one very important thing for the curve (maybe it's just for me) you have to set the U resolution higher else you will have steps.

My render doesn't looks like the work of Mike Campau but I am sure you can make something similar using this technique.

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify this by manipulating a straight object by hand and use a curve modifier. It is much easier to change this not bended object using your favourite technique like sculpting, lattice, skin or completely by hand in edit mode.

Let's start with a curve.
[image]

I will then create a linear extrude and give some variation in the cross section. In this case I will do it by hand  and provide a good enough resolution along the axis using loop cut.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Applying the curve modifier will deform the object along the curve. If the longitudinal resolution is not good enough, the deformed shape will not look continuous. Some tweaking or smoothing may be required.
[image]

Comment: you actually had that problem I mentioned in my post. Your curve looks edgy (if thats actually a word) because you didn't turn up the U Resolution in the curve settings

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another option on how to achieve this, a more "clean" way to do this. Also I think this exactly how the artist did it.

- You have your **3D** curve what has whatever crazy design you can
  make
- Then one **2D** curve that will act as the shape of the brush. Think of it as the shape the bristles would leave on a surface. This will be your **3D** curve bevel object
- And then another **2D** curve that will be the tapper object of the **3D** curve. Subdivide this curve and move/manipulate the handlers and its vertices relative to the beginning and end of the path to bulge the **3D** curve as desired.

[image]

Also make sure the 3d curve type is bezier to take advantage of the possibility to tilt vertices and add a "twist" effect.

[image]